# JQuery browser console error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display an image where the image name comes from a MySQL query via JSON.

My JSON:

```
[{"data":[{"ClientImageName":"1_logo.png","ClientName":"Name","RoomName":"Room 2","RoomFromTime":"06:00","RoomToTime":"17:00"},{"ClientImageName":"1_logo.png","ClientName":"Name","RoomName":"Room 6","RoomFromTime":"06:00","RoomToTime":"23:00"},{"ClientImageName":"1_logo.png","ClientName":"Name","RoomName":"Room 1","RoomFromTime":"07:00","RoomToTime":"17:00"},{"ClientImageName":"1_logo.png","ClientName":"Name","RoomName":"Room 18","RoomFromTime":"07:00","RoomToTime":"23:00"}]}]
```

The jQuery that reads the data is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function get_data() {
        $.getJSON("get_data_logos.php", function(json){
            json = json[0].data;
            var tr ;

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.css("border-bottom","2px solid #FFF");
                tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientimage-text'><img src='../../../../conf_images/boards/'" + json[i].ClientImageName + "></></div></td>");
                tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
                tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
                tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");
                $('table').append(tr);
            }
        });
    }
    get_data();
    setInterval(get_data,60000)
});
```

The line that has the image is:

```
 tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientimage-text'><img src='../../../../conf_images/boards/'" + json[i].ClientImageName + "></></div></td>");
```

When I run the script only a place holder for the image is displayed. When I look at the console I see the following message "You don't have permission to access /apps/conf/conf_images/boards/
on this server."

If I hard code the image name it works fine.

My question is have I written the JQuery correctly with regard to the line of code:

```
tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientimage-text'><img src='../../../../conf_images/boards/'" + json[i].ClientImageName + "></></div></td>");
```

If I inspect the line of code I see:

```html
<img src="../../../../conf_images-boards/" 1_logo.png="">
```

and it should be

```html
<img src="../../../../conf_images-boards/1_logo.png>.
```

Comment: Hi, you try change permission folder conf_images/boards/ with  `chmod 755`  ?

Comment: @Guillermo Andres Fuentes Moral Hi, they are already 755. even tried 777 with no joy. As I say if I hardcode an image name from the same folder it works fine. But because the image names are dynamic it needs to be the variable name that comes from the Json.

Comment: You try print for console this `json[i].ClientImageName` and check if your relative path it's fine, i believe your relative path, can  provocated  this error

Comment: @wmorrell have fixed your problem about syntax, checkout !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientimage-text'><img src='../../../../conf_images/boards/'" + json[i].ClientImageName + "></></div></td>");
```

has incorrect quoting. You want:

```
tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientimage-text'><img src='../../../../conf_images/boards/" + json[i].ClientImageName + "'></></div></td>");
```

Comment: well spotter. I have been looking at this for hours.

Comment: Cheers, it happens to all of us!